# Piping an interactive bash session to a file

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, tee

This question is a follow up on
[Piping an interactive session to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812098/piping-an-interactive-session-to-a-file).

But since I cannot comment in that post, I'll ask here.
I have the following code inside a bash script:

```
tee -a file.log | (ls -a )| tee -a file.log
```

The program runs fine, but I am required to press the enter key for the script to exit.

Is there anyway for the script to exit without an action from the user?

Note: `ls -a` is just an example I am using here to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the first tee to take empty input so it isn't waiting on stdin, like so:

```
tee -a file.log <<< "" | (ls -a )| tee -a file.log
```

or

```
echo | tee -a file.log | (ls -a )| tee -a file.log
```

or

```
tee -a file.log < "" | (ls -a )| tee -a file.log
```

Comment: Notice you lose the ability to provide regular input with this method, so using it for a shell or interpreter might not work as intended