# Is there a way I can log all stdin and stdout to a file while while not influencing it?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a Rust program which uses a [protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html) to communicate with a GUI via stdin and stdout. For debug purposes, I want to be able to see what the communication is, however, the GUI is a completely separate program that doesn't give me access to the console.

The only solution I thought of would be to log everything that comes to stdin/stdout manually in the program, however that's not ideal since I might easily miss something that should be logged (esp. with prints).

Comment: If you're ok with a non-Rust answer and are in a Unix-y environment, the `tee` utility is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes it would be except I have no way of accessing the console when the gui calls my program so I can't pass any commands in there:/

Comment: You could probably modify your gui to call `tee` itself but without knowing how you're invoking the program, it's hard to give you a concrete answer.

Comment: But you could write a tiny script that wraps your program and just clones stdin and stdout. Then have the GUI call the script instead. [This Q&A may help you write such a script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812098/piping-an-interactive-session-to-a-file)

Comment: Sadly I didn't write the gui so can't edit it.

The second answer sounds plausible, but i have already resolved it in the meanwhile by redefining println! and panic! to log as well as do what they normally do; catching stdin is quite easy since obviously Im reading it at some point in the program.

Thanks a lot for your help guys, I'm still curious if there is a better way of doing things.