# How do I output GHCI (commands and result of the commands) to the bash and a text file?

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, sh, ghc

What I want

- To copy the command I input into the GHCI onto a text file

  - For example: I load a file into the GHCI and run a function inside the file I want how I ran the function to be printed to the text file
- To copy the result of the command input even if it is an error. I also want the command and result to show up on the shell like normal. (I'm using this to follow along with my Professor so that I can type in his commands and study them later)
- I would prefer it if I didn't have to type a big command everytime when I run anything on GHCI. So I would like to just load GHCI with a txt file in mind and it will just push everything there. I would also like for it to append to the text file not overwrite.

What I have found so far. . .

- loading ghci with ghci file.hs |& tee -a file.txt works except it doesnt print the commands I input just the results (including errors)
- there is a ghci history located in ~/.ghc/ghci_history which appends the next command I input to GHCI to the top of the file (first line), but does not include the result of the command
- the bash history does not include the GHCI commands I input. The last thing it saves is when I originally loaded into the GHCI

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this could work https://stackoverflow.com/a/18812698/1364288 it uses "process substitution" https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `script` command is for. You can use it like this:

```
% script -a ghci.log -c ghci
Script started, output log file is 'ghci.log'.
GHCi, version 8.10.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> "lul"
"lul"
Prelude> :q
Leaving GHCi.
% cat ghci.log
Script started on 2021-03-17 20:28:31-04:00 [TERM="rxvt-unicode-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/8" COLUMNS="106" LINES="56"]
GHCi, version 8.10.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> "lul"
"lul"
Prelude> :q
Leaving GHCi.
```

Beware that it is quite assiduous in recording everything exactly as it happens -- including color codes, backspaces, and other terminal control sequences -- so you should be careful how you view and edit the resulting log.

Comment: Do you know how to capture the error message as well, not just the return message? The error message I got contains a lot of symbols which is really hard to read or retrieve.

Comment: @Haskell Standard shell tricks should work here, including redirection (`script` implicitly launches a shell to interpret the command you give it). `script -a ghci.log -c "ghci 2>&1"`

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing I would normally automate using something like [expect](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html). For example, take this Expect script:

```
spawn {*}[lrange $argv 0 end]
log_file ghci.log
interact
```

I can run GHCi like so:

```
expect ghci.expect stack ghci
```

The first line is a little redundant, but this gives an example of how you might change the range to e.g. `lrange $argv 1 end` to skip the first argument and use it for something else, like the log file name:

```
spawn {*}[lrange $argv 1 end]
log_file [lindex $argv 0]
interact
```

Invoked like so:

```
expect ghci.expect ghci.log stack ghci
```

Either way, the log file `ghci.log`, which is append by default (use `log_file -noappend` to overwrite), will contain my entire interaction: keyboard entry, standard output, and standard error. I can view the log file using `less -R ghci.log`; `-R` is necessary to pass through the ANSI control codes for colour output and line editing (backspace, arrows, and so on).

This is good enough to copy out portions of the interaction, but the log file itself will be fairly messy because it’s basically logging at the level of keys, so you may need further processing if you want to strip out the control codes. The `interact` command also accepts a block of arguments for defining custom interaction commands, check the linked man page for more info.